# iphone application login/logout buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication

I am developing an iOS app which contains login/authentication functionality. I putted a bar button item in the first view controller and a push segue to a login view controller where I implemented an IBAction with this code

```
    User *userObj = [[User alloc] init];
    NSInteger username = [[self.telnumberTextField text] integerValue];
    NSInteger password = [[self.pwdTextField text] integerValue];
    [userObj loginWithUsername:username andPassword:password];    
    NSUserDefaults *dUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [dUser setInteger:userObj.userId forKey:@"userID"];   
    [dUser synchronize];
    if ( userObj.userId == 0 ) {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erreur"
                                                          message:@"Numero de telephone ou mot de passe incorrect"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles: nil];       
        [message show];
    }
    else
       [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

My question is how to hide/disable the login item bar button (after popToRootViewController)  and put another for user logout instead? where to add code that checks if there is a logged in user, to show login or logout button?

(I viewed some other questions : [login/logout connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183007/login-logout-on-an-iphone-app) and [managing redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749716/how-to-logout-from-an-iphone-application-and-re-direct-it-to-login-page) but my problem seems to be different).
Any help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent view controller should read out some flag that you set after a successful login and should place a different UIBarButtonItem accordingly in the viewWillAppear: method.

As I can see, this flag could be userObj.userID, which should be != 0 as a sign showing that a successful login had taken place.

Comment: Thanks. I will see what is a flag and how to create it then I will try this solution.